# D3 - Select SVG center path when drilled into and display zoom out background image

Tags: d3.js

I'd like to add a background image to the center of this sunburst:

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4348373

so that once the user has clicked to drill into the burst, the center circle instead of being a solid background color would display a "zoom out" background image.

I don't know how to identify the center circle and change the fill color from solid to a background image. The zoom out image would only be displayed when the user has drilled down. When the user is expanded all the way out (the default state when the page is loaded), then the zoom out image would not be displayed.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put another `circle` or `g` element with `circle` and `text` into center and give it

```
yourZoomOutEleement
.attr('opacity',0)
.attr('pointer-events','none')
```

when sunburst is zoomed in, you can display your circle (or `g` with other elements in it) by specifying opacity

`yourZoomOutEleement.attr('opacity',1)`

see the [block](http://blockbuilder.org/anonymous/1b5e5b56c33ef5c8840160da3e403105)

Comment: In the example code here: http://blockbuilder.org/lance-p/a2322501fbf261c2f66d37fbb668a953

can you show me how you would hook this up to show the zoom out icon?

Comment: I have included block as link

Comment: you have to drill before you see effect in this block

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, this is what I was looking for. Thanks!